# What kind of return is that?

Tags: python

Taken from this kata in codewars : [Python Kata](http://www.codewars.com/kata/selective-fear-of-numbers)

> I've got a crazy mental illness. I dislike numbers a lot. But it's a little complicated: The number I'm feared of depends on which day of week it is... This a concrete description of my mental illness:
>
> Monday --> 12
>
> Tuesday --> numbers greater than 95
>
> Wednesday --> 34
>
> Thursday --> 0
>
> Friday --> numbers divisable by 2
>
> Saturday --> 56
>
> Sunday --> 666 or -666
>
> Write a function which takes a string (day of week) and an integer (number to be tested) so it tells the doctor if I'm feared or not. (return a boolean)

and this answer :

```
def am_I_afraid(day,num):
return {
    'Monday':  num == 12,
    'Tuesday': num > 95,
    'Wednesday': num == 34,
    'Thursday': num == 0,
    'Friday': num % 2 == 0,
    'Saturday': num ==  56,
    'Sunday': num == 666 or num == -666,
}[day]
```

Could someone please help me understand how that return works ? (innards)

Is that return's content allocated before being processed ?

Comment: What exactly is your question? Are you asking how the code works?

Comment: It simply returns the value indexed by `day` in the temp dictionary.

Comment: @Onilol this evaluate all values and then retrieve the one by key

Comment: More specifically how that `return` ( in this case ) works

Comment: You really should create your own little tasks rather than some unnecessarily bigger task. If you can't write your own toy programs then you won't learn.  You can investigate your question without writing all that code. You could investigate with just one day of the week for example. And without "mental illness" having any relevance.

Comment: @barlop Sometimes writing your own toy programs you are not aware of the different ways of solving an issue. In this particular case I've never seen a return like that. What does asking for guidance of more experienced people have to do with "mental illness" ? I could take the example as granted and use it randomly.. but I'm trying to understand the why.

Comment: I suggest looking at the code systematically. I've never seen a return like that either, but would probably try assigning that dictionary to a variable, then return `mydict[day]`. If that works and gives the right result, print the dictionary before returning. Just poke it and see what happens, it won't bite.

Comment: @Useless you should change that nickname to Useful ! Thanks for the advice !

Comment: @Onilol Your example said "I've got a crazy mental illness. I dislike numbers a lot."  So presumably your example has something to do with mental illness. And the mental illness part is irrelevant. An example of a toy thing you can try, is simply the kind of thing that useless/useful suggested.  e.g. Try this line in the python interpreter `{'abc':True,'def':False}['def']` You may still have Whys, still worth asking, but you'd be nearer your answer

Comment: @barlop Thank you. Regarding the "mental illness" it's the text quoted from the kata. That return caught me off-guard and I couldn't really think of ways to experiment with it since I'm still low level, but, thanks to you guys I can see the broader picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code runs and evaluates each line in turn, so given an input of 666 you would get a hash of:

```
{'Monday':  False,
    'Tuesday': True,
    'Wednesday': False,
    'Thursday': False,
    'Friday': True,
    'Saturday': False,
    'Sunday': True,
}
```

Then the `[day]` would pluck that value from the hash and return the boolean value, so if `Wednesday` was passed you'll get `False`. If `Friday` was passed, you'll get `True`.  i.e.

```
{'Monday':  False,
        'Tuesday': True,
        'Wednesday': False,
        'Thursday': False,
        'Friday': True,
        'Saturday': False,
        'Sunday': True,
    }['Friday']
```

Will get the hash value: `{'Friday': True}` and return the value `True`.

Comment: Do you mind expanding on the hash concept ?

Comment: Hash is a key/value pairing. aka a dictionary

Comment: The python dictionary is a hash map (look it up if you're interested), but formally the "hash" is some integral value computed from the key and used like an index - it isn't the key-value pair found using that hash.

Comment: -1  My python is fairly rusty, but I see that your code won't run, even {'abc':true} will not run. It must be True, not true.  See what Andy posted, he gets the casing or True right.

Answer (score 3):

This builds a dictionary with each day of the week as a key. The dictionary looks like this (assuming I pass `num` with a value of `10`) (remember dictionaries are unordered)

```
{'Friday': True,
 'Monday': False,
 'Saturday': False,
 'Sunday': False,
 'Thursday': False,
 'Tuesday': False,
 'Wednesday': False}
```

What it is doing is evaluating each expression with `num`:

```
num == 12   # False
num > 95    # False
num == 34   # False
num == 0    # False
num % 2 == 0 # True
num ==  56  # False
num == 666 or num == -666  # False
```

Finally, it's using the passed `day` to only return the value of that key in the dictionary.

So, if you pass `Friday` and `10`, you'll receive `True`. For every other day and a value of `10` you get `False`

Answer (score 0):

Well this is a dictionary of string and boolean. Each time this method is called based on the number passed to it it computes the boolean values for all the day of the week. Then at the end it index the dictionary for the passed day and return its value.

Comment: So it evaluates the `value` of each `key` and returns the one that matches?

Comment: It computes the value for all the days of the week and then return the value of the specific day you passed to it as an input

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary literals (and also all other object literals) are usable in all the same ways as any other object of that type. That is to say, this:

```
def am_I_afraid(day,num):
    return {
        'Monday':  num == 12,
        'Tuesday': num > 95,
        'Wednesday': num == 34,
        'Thursday': num == 0,
        'Friday': num % 2 == 0,
        'Saturday': num ==  56,
        'Sunday': num == 666 or num == -666,
    }[day]
```

is exactly equivalent to this:

```
def am_I_afraid(day,num):
    my_dict = {
        'Monday':  num == 12,
        'Tuesday': num > 95,
        'Wednesday': num == 34,
        'Thursday': num == 0,
        'Friday': num % 2 == 0,
        'Saturday': num ==  56,
        'Sunday': num == 666 or num == -666,
    }
    return my_dict[day]
```

Using dictionaries like this is an occasionally-seen alternative to the "case" statement seen in other languages. It is essentially a 'short hand' way of writing a series of `if`s, like this:

```
if day == 'Monday':
    return num == 12
elif day == 'Tuesday':
    return num > 95
elif day == 'Wednesday':
    return num == 34
```

and so on.